# Split numbers and words from user supplied data

Tags: php

I have the following code on my index.php file

```
<?php
$string = $_GET['string'];
$month = '';
$day = '';
?>
```

If string is like "apr12" or "12apr",
then $month should be "apr" and $day should be "12"
else both $month & $day should be blank.

Comment: And you tried something or just want us to do it for you?

Comment: Yes. And what have you tried so far? Where is your code failing. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Yeah i'm so sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fact that day is only numbers and month is only chars, so it may look like this:

```
$string = $_GET['string'];
$month = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/i','',$string));
$day = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/','',$string);
if (!in_array($month, ['jan'/* ... and other valid values */], true)) {
  $month = '';
}
if ($day === '' || (int)$day < 1 || (int)$day > 31) {
  $day = '';
}
// Then validate your input further
```

Comment: That was too fast. Thank you so much